# How to load the right version of jquery in asp.net/c#?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, browser

In my asp.net solution, I am loading a jquery library, but I want to use the right version. By this I mean, version 1.10.1 if the browser is IE version 8 or less, and version 2.0.2 if the browser is not IE, or is IE and version 9 or higher.

As well, it needs to take into consideration, which type of doctype and metatag is used. If it ends up doing a IE8 document standards on IE9 or IE10 for example, then it should load the jquery 1.10.1.

This is how I load my jquery library for example in my `.ascx` file:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="jquery_ui_js" name="/_layouts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" runat="server" OnDemand="False" Localizable="False" />
```

I would prefer to do this check and load the right one in the asp.net code (`.ascx` file).

Does anyone know how to do this?

I was thinking about something like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But not sure how to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (!IE)]><!-->
    <script src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Obviously, you will need to adjust the paths if necessary, but that is the gist.

Comment: what about, if its not IE?

Comment: Answer updated to include | (!IE) logic, which matches browsers that are NOT IE, in conditional comment. Sorry I did not see your non-IE reference in your question.

Comment: Also whats `<!-->` for? Its not in the first if statement.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work in firefox 22 beta 5.

Comment: The <!--> makes IE9 and non-IE browsers "see" the second script tag, no matter what is in the condition, because of their ability to understand nested comments; whereas IE8 and earlier see lines 4 through 6 as one big conditional comment. This essentially makes the | (!IE) logic useless and is there more for human understanding.

Comment: I would bet that beta versions, or nightly builds, of Firefox and Chrome Canary would not necessarily work. Have you tried Firefox 21?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32051/discussion-between-karl-and-omega)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with migrate plugin also.
This will work with latest version of jquery.

for more documentation http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/